# AWS The lambda function is not triggered by S3 after an upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform-provider-aws, eventtrigger

I have a problem with AWS Lambda and S3.

I deploy all my AWS architecture with terraform. I have a bucket in which I can upload XML files which triggers a lambda to process these files (the events are well informed).

The problem is that after the deployment of my architecture, when I drop an XML file in my bucket, nothing happens the first few times. As if the first files I upload are not taken into account and S3 doesn't send a notification to Lambda.

Sometimes I have to send several files to S3 before it starts to be taken into account or I modify with the GUI the notifications in the S3 console, without changing anything and just by clicking on "Save". I don't know how to investigate this problem.

Could you tell me if anyone has ever had a similar case?
Also, would you know if it is possible to see a history of everything that happens on an S3 bucket (uploaded files, sent events, ...) to investigate my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have Cloudwatch enabled for Lambda's? A PutObject trigger on an S3 bucket to a Lambda should trigger on every event, so tracking what happens to these events in Cloudwatch would be the first thing I would look at

Comment: How do you know the lambda hasn't been triggered? Is it because the action the lambda should perform hasn't been performed, or because you've checked the lambda cloudwatch logs and can see the lambda has not been invoked? There's a world of difference between the two. I suspect it's the former, which will be due to a problem in that lambda's code, and can explain it intermittently failing.

Comment: Can you share configuration of bucket? When you enable notification to Lambda. Follow: Bucket > Properties > Events Best regards.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answers. I said that the lambda is never trigerred when I upload the first objects because when I look on the CloudWatch logs for the lambda there is no logs and we can see that the lambda is not called.

Comment: My bucket event is on every object created on the folder upload/ with the extension ".xml", trigger the lambda

Comment: Do you know if this is possible to see an history of all notifications sent by AWS S3 to see if the event is sent or if the probleme is here

Comment: I did a test again this afternoon, I'm deploying my architecture with terraform. I upload a file in my bucket, the lambda is never called, no logs in cloudwatch. I wait 15 minutes, I upload again a file in my bucket and this time the lambda is well called, without having modified anything in the S3 or Lambda configuration.

Comment: I know this sounds basic, but have you tried uploading an object that does not trigger the lambda, then uploading the exact same object again? If it never triggers the lambda, even on second upload, its something to do with the object creation event settings or the object format, if it triggers it on the re-upload, its something new to me.

Comment: Hi, this is what I do. The upload of the same object 5 minutes later trigger the lambda. I feel like there's a kind of latency between the time I set up the event and the time it's actually active.

Answer (score 1):

The key to what you are experiencing is that it occurs right after you create the bucket and the trigger.  A lot of AWS systems have an eventual consistency model. In the case of S3 both objects and the buckets have eventual consistency across 3 Availability Zones.

In short, you are putting an object to one of the S3 instances before the event trigger on that instance of S3.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. I'm not sure I understand, all the architecture I deploy is only in one region on AWS. Is there some kind of latency before the first events are actually triggered?

Comment: In short, yes expect a latency for configuration change to take effect.